# Linkedin Refreshing An Access Token

Tags: linkedin-api, spring-social

I've some troubles whit spring-social-api for linkedin. After 60 days access token expires and I can't use it to post on timeline of access token user. There is a way to pass this mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Repeating my answer from http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?138943-Linkedin-refresh-accesstoken :

Although I can't honestly say I've tried it with LinkedIn, you should be able to obtain the connection (via a ConnectionRepository) and call refresh() on it. In fact, this should work with any OAuth2-secured API (except for Facebook who doesn't quite play by the OAuth2 spec).

I've not tried it with LinkedIn yet, because up until recently Spring Social was working with LinkedIn via their OAuth 1.0a authentication. But it sounds like a good thing to test.

Therefore, Spring Social supports refresh of access tokens. But it is a manual effort on your part to (1) catch the ExpiredAuthorizationException, (2) use ConnectionRepository to fetch the Connection, and (3) call refresh() to update the connection.

What would be more awesome is if Spring Social were to somehow catch that ExpiredAuthorizationException for you, automatically call refresh() and then reattempt the call that triggered the exception; making it seamless for the caller. That is something I've been pondering, but there's no implementation yet.

One possible solution is an aspect. But it'd need to be configured by the developer to properly wrap whatever API binding types (LinkedInTemplate, for example) the application is using. Another option I'm thinking over is to dig down into AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding and configure the RestTemplate that it exposes to handle that exception. It's a bit iffy on whether it can work, but if it does work, then any API binding that extends AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding would automatically get refresh capability...except, again, for Facebook who doesn't play by OAuth2 rules.

Comment: Checking the docs here I think LinkedIn's mechanism for "refreshing" the access token is actually the same as the original authorization process. It looks like they don't provide refresh tokens that can be used to get new access tokens programmaticaly with a backend API call. refresh() wouldn't handle that case, would it? It seems like you'd have to make sure to periodically send the users through the authorization flow to maintain a fresh token. http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens

Comment: Right. After I wrote that answer, I realized that LinkedIn doesn't implement refresh tokens and instead requires you go through the authorization flow again (Facebook does it this way, too). It's a bit annoying that it differs from the spec, but it is arguably more secure this way. In any event, Spring Social's ReconnectFilter should be able to handle this scenario perfectly. It's now available in Spring Social 1.1.0.M3.